# Struggling to populate from a pair of API's in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, object

Working on modifying a project I'm learning from.
The initial project is to create a sort of infinitely scrolling Twitter Clone. Posts were grabbed from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ api, and I'm trying to add another level by bringing in images from another image placeholder API.
I'm a noob, so I was able to successfully grab data from both API's and populate the DOM. Trouble is, with my current structure, I'm repeating placeholder images as what I'm grabbing from the placeholder api is in 5 object blocks. Could use some help in making sure every post has a different photo. Thanks, total newb here. Wondering if I should just be populating an array of objects and working from there, but maybe there's a shortcut I'm missing?

```
const postsContainer = document.getElementById("posts-container");
const loading = document.querySelector(".loader");
const filter = document.getElementById("filter");

let limit = 5;
let page = 1;

//Fetch Posts from API
async function getPosts() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=${limit}&_page=${page}`
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}

//Fetch Photos from another API
async function getPhoto(photo) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api`);
  const data = await res.json();
  photo = data.results[0].picture.thumbnail;
  return photo;
}

//Show items in DOM
async function showPosts() {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  const pic = await getPhoto();

  posts.forEach((post) => {
    const postEl = document.createElement("div");
    postEl.classList.add("post");
    postEl.innerHTML = `
        <div class="number">
          <img class="profile-pic" src="${pic}" alt="user photo" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-info">
          <h2 class="post-title">${post.title}</h2>
          <p class="post-body">
           ${post.body}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      `;

    postsContainer.appendChild(postEl);
  });
}

//Show loader and fetch more posts

function showLoading() {
  loading.classList.add("show");

  setTimeout(() => {
    loading.classList.remove("show");
    setTimeout(() => {
      page++;
      showPosts();
    }, 1000);
  }, 300);
}

//Show initial posts

showPosts();

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;

  if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 5) {
    showLoading();
  }
});
```

GitHub Repo: `https://github.com/unsubstantiated-Script/infinite-scroller`

TIA

Comment: put `const pic = await getPhoto();` inside the `posts.forEach(async post => {`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Needed to move the pic variable inside my forEach loop. That and async the forEach loop.